# Updating / forcing usb wireless driver in Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers

I have a new USB WIFI stick Airlive X.USB-3. It's a a/b/g/n solution with dual external atennas based ar9170 chipset.

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ar9170 website states that the mentioned usb device id is now in the compatible hardware list for this driver.

However, I'am using Debian 6.0 on Alix 1D board, and when issuing:
*modinfo ar9170usb*

the list does not contain alias entry for my usb device.

My question is how to update this driver or force it to work with my device.

Many thanks in advance.

**Update 2011-03-07:**

My kernel version is: **2.6.32-5-686**, output of modinfo ar9170usb:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ar9170/ar9170usb.ko
firmware:       ar9170-2.fw
firmware:       ar9170-1.fw
firmware:       ar9170.fw
description:    Atheros AR9170 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Christian Lamparter <chunkeey@web.de>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
alias:          usb:v057Cp8402d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v057Cp8401d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04BBp093Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v2019p5304d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v083ApF522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0026d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0586p3417d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v1435p0326d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v1435p0804d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0ACEp1221d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9040d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3A09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C10d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:vCACEp0300d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p1011d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p1010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p1002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p1001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p9170d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        mac80211,usbcore,led-class,ath,cfg80211
vermagic:       2.6.32-5-686 SMP mod_unload modversions 686
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
parm:           ht:enable MPDU aggregation. (bool)
```

Comment: which kernel do you have ? and which version of the driver ?

Answer (score 0):

The stick works well with the carl9170 driver: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170

I think you would need a kernel update.
I have it running on Ubuntu 11.04 using kernel 2.6.38